# How to fix an HTTP 403 error when webscraping in R?

Tags: html, css, r, xml

I'm trying to gather statistical data on 3,600 + Wikipedia pages for work. I am trying to automate it using web scraping in R.

I have an issue extracting the HTML code directly in R.

```
download_html("xtools.wmflabs.org/articleinfo/fr.wikipedia.org/1re_Convention_nationale_acadienne")
```

And this is what the console tells me:

```
download_html("xtools.wmflabs.org/articleinfo/fr.wikipedia.org/1re_Convention_nationale_acadienne")
Error in curl::curl_download(url, file, quiet = quiet, mode = mode, handle = handle) : HTTP error 403.
```

What would be a possible reason this isn't working?

When I save the HTML as a file and run it through R, everything works perfectly and I get to make a dataframe with the results:

```
# ID webpage link first
setwd("C:\\Users\\judit\\Scraping dans R")
webpage <- read_html("HTML_1e.html")
# read_html("https://xtools.wmflabs.org/articleinfo/fr.wikipedia.org/1re_Convention_nationale_acadienne?uselang=fr")


# Statistiques: extraction ----

# Stats: titre
titre <- html_nodes(webpage, ".back-to-search+ a")
titre <- html_text(titre, trim=TRUE)

# Stats: Taille de page
taille <- html_nodes(webpage, ".col-lg-5 tr:nth-child(3) td+ td")
taille <- html_text(taille, trim=TRUE)

# Stats: Total des modifications
mod <- html_nodes(webpage, ".col-lg-5 tr:nth-child(4) td+ td")
mod <- html_text(mod, trim=TRUE)

# Stats: Nombre de redacteurs
red <- html_nodes(webpage, ".col-lg-5 tr:nth-child(5) td+ td")
red <- html_text(red)

# Stats: Evaluation
evaluation <- html_nodes(webpage, ".col-lg-5 tr:nth-child(6) td+ td")
evaluation <- html_text(evaluation, trim=TRUE)

# Stats: Liens vers cette page
liens_vers <- html_nodes(webpage, ".stat-list--group tr:nth-child(2) a")
liens_vers <- html_text(liens_vers, trim=TRUE)

# Stats: Liens depuis cette page
liens_depuis <- html_nodes(webpage, ".col-lg-offset-1 .stat-list--group tr:nth-child(4) td+ td")
liens_depuis <- html_text(liens_depuis, trim=TRUE)

# Stats: Mots
mots <- html_nodes(webpage, ".col-lg-3 tr:nth-child(3) td+ td")
mots <- html_text(mots, trim=TRUE)

wikipedia <- data.frame(titre, taille, red, mod, evaluation, liens_vers, liens_depuis)
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated!
PS: Pardon my French in the code. It's my first language.

Comment: I've run into this before with a particular website, and my interpretation (totally uneducated) was that the website was deciding I was a hacker and blocking me. I was able to run the same code a few minutes later and either never get a 403 error or get it on a different URL, and I decided not to troubleshoot further.

Comment: Yes exactly, when I do the work manually, after opening enough pages it asks me to sign in because it thinks I'm a robot. Maybe I need to find a way to sign in through R?

Comment: If you are trying to rapidly download a large number of files in a short period of time, the website may have a quote on the number of page requests per second.  Use the  `Sys.sleep()` function to add a delay between each page request.  If you use 0.5 to 1sec delay(maybe slightly less), it should prevent a quote violation.

Comment: @Dave2e, that sounds like an excellent general solution to this problem. Would you be willing to write it up as an answer? A few months ago that answer would have been really helpful for some code I was working on :-)

Comment: @Dave2e thanks for the heads up! I haven't yet started running the code on more than one page at a time, but I'm sure this will be usefull when I get to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those looking also at extracting data from Wikipedia pages, I found some packages that help me circumvent the 403 issue by directly getting my data from R.

I use the following packages:

- WikipediR
- WikipediaR

This is my code for gathering basic information on the article:

```
# Basic information ----

library("WikipediR")

pageinfo <- page_info(language = "fr", 
                      project = "wikipedia", 
                      page = "1re Convention nationale acadienne",
                      properties = c("url"),
                      clean_response = T)

pageinfo_df1=data.frame(pageinfo)
pageinfo_df2=data.frame(id=pageinfo_df1$pageid, title=pageinfo_df1$title, lang=pageinfo_df1$pagelanguage, sizeBytes=pageinfo_df1$length, url=pageinfo_df1$fullurl)
```

And then to gather some specific data that was available through XTools, I now use coding to get it directly from Wikipedia as follows:

```
# Links from this article
links_page <- links(page = "1re Convention nationale acadienne", domain = "fr")
links_page_df <- as.data.frame(links_page$links)
nrow(links_page_df)
```

Some data is quite hard to gather without getting a 403 or 404 error while webscraping. Since this is only my second project in R, I might change the data I'm collecting so that I'm using easier to find data.